# Can't get the ApplyCurrentValues(Entity) to work in Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, .net-4.5

Comrades, can anyone help me out here, entity framework 5 seems not to have ApplyCurrentValues() method. Is there another way to update the database object in entity framework v5. here is what am trying to do

```
odc.Accounts.Attach(new Account { AccountID = account.AccountID });
  odc.Accounts.ApplyCurrentValues(account);
  odc.SaveChanges();
```

But i have been getting compile error in the **ApplyCurrentValues()** line

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ApplyCurrentValues` is an `ObjectContext` API method, so first you have to gain access to the objectcontext that is wrapped in the `DbContext`:

```
odc.Accounts.Attach(new Account { AccountID = account.AccountID });
((IObjectContextAdapter)odc).ObjectContext
    .ApplyCurrentValues("Accounts", account);
odc.SaveChanges();
```

Note that the wrapped context does not have members like "Accounts", so you have to use the `ObjectContext` method itself.

But you can do the same using the DbContext API:

```
var sourceAcc = new Account { AccountID = account.AccountID });
odc.Entry(account).CurrentValues.SetValues(sourceAcc);
```

Comment: Thanks @Gert, the code works now, but why is it that it does'nt work in EF 5 but works in version 4 and below?

Comment: I think you inadvertently started using the DbContext API when switching to EF 5. Check the base type of you `odc` variable.

Comment: Good answer. I just noticed, that `ApplyCurrentValues` returns `sourceAcc` with **Modified** or **Unchanged** state depending on the case. It does nothing with `account` instance which is still **Detached**. I think it maight be explicitly shown. I'm also bit confused with variable names. In sample with EF5 `account` represents entity from the database. Previously it represented the detached one.